# Formatting only one column in an PHP-generated HTML table

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using PHP to auto-generate an HTML table and I want the second column to be right-aligned. I read somewhere that you can use `<tgroup>` and `<colspec>` to do this. Here's my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbase");
$sql="SELECT Document, COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE event LIKE 'Photo%' GROUP BY Document ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
};
$colNames = array_keys(reset($data));
echo "<table id='topTen'><tgroup><colspec column='2' align='right'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>Photo</th><th>Counts</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    echo "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
    }   
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</tbody></tgroup></table>";
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

But it doesn't work. Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat crude way - simply check if second `<td>` is == 2, if it is, add styling (not tested):

```
$style = ''; //set var
foreach($data as $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
  $i=1; // start counter
  foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    if($i == 2){
      $style = ' style="text-align: right"'; // style if second col
    }
    echo "<td$style>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
    $style = ''; // reset style var
    $i++;
  }   
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: It will also affect the 4th, 6th etc.. columns if there are

Comment: It will affect 4th, 6th etc `<td>` which is always the 2nd column - as OP requested

Comment: So you are saying that a 2nd column is also the 4th and the 6th ? Ok, so if you only want to affect the 2nd one, how do you say it ?

Comment: This is assuming you only have 2 fields, and you don't know that. So not very adaptive.
By the way, the first time you will pass through your foreach, you'll have an undefined value $style

Comment: It works and I'll use the same technique to adjust the width as well. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed. And @rrd's post below seems to offer a way to do that (admittedly for an id but just as easily for a class I guess). Will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#topTen tr td:first-child + td { text-align:right; }
```

This targets ONLY the second column (as opposed to using td:nth-child(2) which will target every second column, but this assumes you have more than two columns).